Why are Spring converters package protected?
In Spring Batch, job parameters are converted from strings to the declared type, using a JobParametersConverter. The default implementation wraps a (Spring Core) ConversionService, which actually converts the arguments passed.
The DefaultConversionService is not suitable for my needs (different formats used), so I'm using a custom JobParametersConverter which wraps a GenericConversionService and I registers only the custom converters needed (e.g. a custom string to date converter).
In this way, I lost some converters, for example StringToArrayConverter, which is extremely handy to pass comma-separated lists to Spring Batch, as the element type is encoded in the class name (e.g. it is possible to pass a job parameter with type [Ljava.util.Date;).
Sadly, StringToArrayConverter is package protected, and the only way to not reimplement it is to register it via DefaultConversionService::addCollectionConverters, but this method also adds several other converters.
Is there a reason for this visibility choice?
